# Use IP list in CSV in python

Tags: python, csv, ip

So, I ahve this list of IP's in a CSV file. Only one column, if I cat the file they all appear on different lines and the file command tells me it is ASCII text.

However, when I try to loop though the file and resolve the addesses for the different IP:s I get the error "socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host".

For some reason the value of the cell isnt properly a string, and I have trouble converting it to one.

```
from string import rstrip
from socket import gethostbyaddr

csv_file = open('csv_list.csv', "r")

for line in csv_file:
    dns_name = gethostbyaddr(str(line.rstrip('\n')))
    print "IP: " + line.rstrip('\n') + "DNS Name:" + dns_name[0]
```

Is there any way around this? I have been thinking about converting the file to a plain textfile, adding all the values from the file to a list so far but I am not sure what the best solution would be.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample input data would be handy...

Comment: No need to `str()` the line, it is already a string. Try `gethostbyaddr(line.strip())` (strip *all* whitespace, not just the newline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the reading of the file (this can be optimized using `with ...`, too) but that one IP cannot be looked up reversely. The `gethostbyaddr` function throws an exception in that case.

I've made up your sample a bit and now it reports errors not as a crash with an exception but prints out a message.

```
from string import rstrip
from socket import gethostbyaddr

with open('csv_list.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        ip = line.strip()
        try:
            dns_name = gethostbyaddr(ip)
            print "IP: %s, DNS Name: %s" % (ip, dns_name[0])
        except Exception, e:
            print "IP: %s, DNS lookup error: %s" % (ip, e)
```

For example for this list of IPs:

```
1.2.3.4
8.8.8.8
4.4.4.4
bad IP
1.2.3
```

it prints

```
IP: 1.2.3.4, DNS lookup error: [Errno 1] Unknown host
IP: 8.8.8.8, DNS Name: google-public-dns-a.google.com
IP: 4.4.4.4, DNS lookup error: [Errno 1] Unknown host
IP: bad IP, DNS lookup error: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
IP: 1.2.3, DNS lookup error: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

Comment: Thank you! Never realized that was tha actual problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try numpy loadtxt to create array from a file.

```
    from numpy import loadtxt
    ip_list = loadtxt("filename.csv", unpack=True)
```